# Default data sent from client to the server

Tags: php, client

I am building this class in PHP to gather everything that is known to my server from a client,
this happens when a client redirects to my http://. DomainName . ending ,

I have looked for few basic things as a start : IP address , time , port , agent , host , host

Basically everything changing that `$_SERVER` includes, my question is :

What additional information I could gather to maximize available information about users that enter my domain?

I forgot to ask,will I have to filter and (how they say,santise?) date from global variables in this case the `$_SERVER` array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use geolocation checking in order to determine where your users are located.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190734/php-geolocation

In case you will support multiple language for ur site it would be easier for you to redirect the users to the right site automatically.

$_SERVER contains almost everything you might want to know really.

Comment: You mentioned that $_SERVER ALMOST includes everything,could you please explain what other things ma-yet be missing,in addition I am looking at the link you have provided me

Comment: An example of data that you need but $_SERVER does not give you is $_REQUEST http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php . i would suggest you start with the important bits first and then you grow from there. i suppose trying to gather everything available could be a bit of an overkill. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You could begin recording what links they're using, what pages they're visiting and how often.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Using mySQL databases, you could create a table logging every page request by their IP and date using `getdate()`.

Comment: of-course ,you mean to track their behavior on my server,Alright thank you for that one

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [irongeek.com's browser info page](http://www.irongeek.com/browserinfo.php) for an example of what information is readily available. You can learn a lot about a client from javascript. Perhaps part of your PHP class should include an AJAX component. That said snooping information available to javascript could be a huge violation of privacy, I'm no expert on ethics on the web.

Another good example of information gathering is Google Analytics (GA) if you have a live site with with GA on it, you should login and look at some of different reports and data types it has.

You should also read about [Do Not Track](https://www.google.com/search?q=Do%20not%20track).